# Quick sort is recurring infinitely

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

First I would like to thank you in advance. 
I tried to write a quick sort in python3, but it recurs infinitely.
Here's my code:

```
def partition(lst, l, h):
    lst.append(float("inf"))
    pivot = lst[0]
    i, j = l+1, h
    while i < j:
        while lst[i] < pivot:
            i += 1
        while lst[j] > pivot:      
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            lst[i] , lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
        else:
            lst = lst[1:i] + [pivot] + lst[i:]
    return lst[:-1], i

def quickSort(lst, l, h):
    if l < h-1:
        mid = (l + h)//2
        lst[l:h], mid = partition(lst[l:h], 0, h-l)
        quickSort(lst, l, mid)
        quickSort(lst, mid, h)
        lst1 = [10, 12, 8, 16, 2, 6, 3, 9, 5]
        quickSort(lst1, 0, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

In recursive algorithms, you should be careful about the initial step of the algorithm. For example, in your case, you need to sort the given array manually without any recursion with the size of 2.